# Entity Framework query loading a lot of related data in Web API throws timeout EntityCommandExecutionException

Tags: sql-server, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities

I have a Web API that uses Entity Framework to load data from SQL Server 2012.

I have created a repository and using Ninject and an interface I use the concrete class in the Web API.

In some Get requests I will need to provide JSON data which is not so big as a graph but the relationships are pretty normalized.

I have mapped the entities to models that returned to the client in JSON format.

So, in the following query I need all this data.

```
var result = _dbContext.Quotes.Where(
                    quote => quote.UserId == user.MemberId)
                    .Include(quote => quote.AdditionalRequirements)
                    .Include(quote => quote.QuoteSpecialRequirements.Select(qsr => qsr.RequirementType))
                    .Include(quote => quote.City)
                    .Include(quote => quote.Country)
                    .Include(quote => quote.Area)
                    .Include(quote => quote.Rooms.Select(room => room.RoomType)).ToList();
```

If I call the service this will result to an `EntityCommandExecutionException` with InnerException a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` and message "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.", which in turn have an InnerException `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception` with message "The wait operation timed out".

Now I'm thinking what will happen when my data grows and how to consider handling this and make it efficient for the future.

Alternatives? Is the query needs restructuring?

I'm thinking, should I extend the timeout expiration value in the web api?

The operations is not yet awaitable, thinking if wrapping them in a Task.Run will improve the performance in a Web API call.

Another solution would be to go to SQL Server procedures.

[EDIT]

A diagram screenshot with the related tables in the database.

[Diagram Screenshot](http://www.flickr.com/photos/94865420@N02/10460177473/)

Here is the query that is created from Entity Framework, used a profiler and got it.

[SQL Query](http://sdrv.ms/1c0nNEJ)

Thank you.

Comment: If the amount of data being queried with all those `include`s is just too much for your server (I can only guess but maybe it's under heavy load?) then it might be more efficient to not `include` all those related entities in the initial query, but retrieve them with a second query after getting the initial collection of `Quote` entities. You could also try grabbing the SQL generated using SQL Profiler and manually execute in SSMS with Query plan shown, this might indicate where you have missing indexes, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I think the database is normalized good enough and I want all this data to return to a client request. I will maybe try with a second query projection and see the results. I'll use a profiler too.

Comment: Good stuff. The problem might be simply that if the database is being heavily updated then you have lots of locks coming and going on those related entity tables, which can cause a large query trying to read all of the data at once to time out. By splitting into two separate operations that can help. But profiling it will show the truth :) Be sure and let us know how you get on!

Comment: I will get on it first chance and edit the question with results. Will attach maybe a screenshot of the database tables regarding the query for your review.

Comment: Also note:  it looks like the design above does not take advantage of the genius of SQL Server, in handling JOINs.  The above looks like it will generate multiple SQL queries -- like separate queries for "RequirementType" and "RoomType".  (As Stephen points out, running a trace in SQL Profiler while the above executes can show that.)  In that case, consider whether you can combine the SQL queries into 1 query:  using JOINs (possibly LEFT OUTER JOINs) to get RequirementType and RoomType in the original query.  JOINing in SQL will probably make it all run much faster.

Comment: It's possible that some *de*normalization may help you speed up. I've heard of some places that have a (denormalized) NoSQL store in front of their SQL backend for performance reasons. `await Task.Run` will not help your situation at all.

Comment: I understanf Stephen, thank you for your comment, I thought so too, it's HTTP after all. I don't think I want to (denormalize) the db in the current state this way. I have edited the question with a screenshot of a diagram showing the regarding tables.